# get only the numeric value of CSS variable, without its type

Tags: css, css-variables

I want to make some calculation in CSS and use the result as a non-typed value.
This is what I've tried:

```css
:root {
  --scale: 100vh / 1920;
}

canvas {
  height: 1920px;
  width: 1080px;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
}
```

Nah, it didn't work, because **--scale** is some value in vh, like **.8vh** or **1.1vh**, but I need it to be just a float, as **.8** or **1.1**.
Is there any way to use that variable without the type (vh), only with its numeric value? (I would prefer to do this with CSS only, without JS)
I need the initial values of height and width to be those, because I'll export the canvas as a png with that size, and scale does affect only the visualization, not the render of the canvas context.

**Edit**:
I've solved this with JS:

```js
  const resize = () => {
    const ratio = (window.innerHeight) / 1920;
    // container is a div wrapping the canvas
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
    containers.forEach(container => {
      const minMarginHeight = Math.min(0, (ratio - 1)/2 * container.clientHeight);
      const minMarginWidth = Math.min(0, (ratio - 1)/2 * container.clientWidth);
      container.style.transform = `scale(${ratio})`;
      container.style.margin = `${minMarginHeight}px ${minMarginWidth}px`;
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    resize();
  });
```

but I was still looking for a pure CSS solution...

Comment: Then why define scale in `vh` in the first place?

Comment: From currently available functions refer from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_functions.asp), [here](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-to-css-functions/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Functions). I don't see any function to get only number value.

Comment: This [post](https://pqina.nl/blog/how-to-prevent-scrolling-the-page-on-ios-safari/) will help you define a `css` variable and calculate it later with `js`.

Comment: @Paulie_D to make it responsible to the viewport size. That's the whole idea of this question. The canvas should have the size of the screen. (The canvas is a rectangle, so the height is the reference I want)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `canvas` element with some wrapper (`.wrapper` in Code snippet) and define CSS `--scale` variable in `.wrapper` to 100%. In case of `%` it can be calculated in `calc` function and you will get your `scale` size.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #673ab7;
  
  --scale: calc(100% / 2);
}

canvas {
  background: tomato;
  transform: scale(var(--scale, 1));
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas />
</div>
```